# Add frame count overlay without other change in codec property

Tags: video, ffmpeg, codec, hevc

I am trying to include frame count overlay on an hevc video using FFmpeg. However, the video is getting re-encoded in the h.264 codec. I want to retain all coding properties (same as before) of the video.

Is it possible by any command to add frame count without altering the video codec and other coding properties?

I used the following command:

ffmpeg -i Video1.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text='%{frame_num}': x=100 : y=50 : box=1" -y out1.mp4

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Video1.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
Duration: 00:00:01.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 145 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv), 416x240, 138 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 1200k tbc (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (hevc) -> drawtext
drawtext -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)

Another command I tried :

ffmpeg -i Video1.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=text='%{frame_num}': x=100 : y=50 : box=1" -vcodec hevc -y out1.mp4

However, this command also results in changing of the coding properties/parameters of the video.

PS- I am using windows cmd line.

PS- Is it possible with minimal changes in coding property? I want to retain all slice NAL unit types, all Profiles and all levels as before. However, all the original NAL unit changes. Specifically, for example, all sub-layers are converted to the base layer and TSA pictures convert to other types.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There is no solution without re-encoding.

Simplified long answer: A video bitstream is a compact representation of the pixel content. To make it compact (i.e. compression), spatial and temporal redundancies existing in the pixels are exploited in a predictive manner. When you change some pixels (e.g. your timestamp) the encoder most likely changes its prediction schemes, since your newly introduced pixels are now representing a different redundancy pattern. As a result, a new encoding with new parameters is needed.

But what if you somehow mange to impose the same encoding parameters (i.e. no re-encoding):

In this scenario, as a consequence of the above predictive aspect, changing any pixel would trigger a chain of changes in other pixels, called error drift. To give you an order of this chain, I can tell you that, depending on the position/importance of pixels, sometimes changing one single pixel results in consequent changes in literally millions of pixels. And in your problem we are talking about a timestamp of several pixels that is supposed to be burnt at every frame.

Comment: Is it possible with minimal changes in coding property? I want to retain all slice NAL unit types, all Profiles and all levels as before. However, all the original NAL unit changes. Specifically, for example, all sub-layers are converted to the base layer and TSA pictures convert to other types.